# MassTransit Check if queue and exchange exist

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using dotnet with masstransit rabbitmq.

I was wondering if there's a way to check if a specific exchange and queue exist. I have 2 services that connect to the same rabbitmq and are started at the same time. One services does all of the queue/exchange setup; I want the 2nd service to do while loop check to see if the queue/exchange exist before proceeding.

I was trying to look at the documentation to see if I could find some examples, but could not locate any. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MassTransit does not generally support this type of coupling behavior, since it ends up linking the consuming service to the producing service. There are plenty of other solutions in MassTransit to support your needs, such as sending messages directly to a queue using `queue:name` as the destination address.

As such, there aren't any built-in methods to check queue/exchange existence in MassTransit.

Comment: That is very useful to know. Thanks! I would like to avoid sending to the queue if possible. I was wondering what are some other solutions that mass transit provides?

I did try sending to the queue directly, but it creates the queue. Is there a way to only send the message if the queue exist?

Comment: Looking into this further. I found https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/659, which may solve my need. Will continue to look into